# How to lint javascript object errors and fix them automatically?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, eslint, lint

Let's say I have this object:

```
const obj = {
  ul: { padding: "20px 0", flex: 1 }, // <- there's a comma here!
  li: { fontFamily: "'Lato'", lineHeight: "44px" }
}
```

Someone accidentally removes a comma separating two values:

```
const obj = {
  ul: { padding: "20px 0", flex: 1 } // <-- oops! the comma that was here is gone...
  li: { fontFamily: "'Lato'", lineHeight: "44px" }
}
```

Now eslint would say something like "Unexpected token", but will not be able to solve the error automatically with `--fix`. Is there a rule I can use to solve these type of issues automatically?

I've looked at rules like [comma-dangle](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-property-newline) and [object-property-newline](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-property-newline) but they don't seem to apply to this situation.

Comment: Auto fix syntax errors? doubt it....

Comment: Wouldn’t this be the job of something like prettier? Also you’re asking for a tool recommendation which is off topic.

Comment: @epascarello Yup. I'm just getting used to using eslint. I already use a couple of rules to improve my experience but I just want to check what else can I do with it, if what I'm asking is too far fetch I'll adjust my expectations of it

Comment: @evolutionxbox I can edit that out so the question is just about eslint. I use prettier too but since there's an "Unexpected token" error it doesn't work, which may be a good thing since it's telling me something is wrong with my code

Comment: Eslint can fix simple errors. Run `eslint --fix`?

Comment: eslint and prettier are there to make sure your code is written in a uniform way. It is not going to fix bad coding. It is going to fix commas, whitespace, and semicolons based on rules you set. It is not a magic problem solving script.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you, the prettier suggestion was nice since it will not allow me to save if there's an error like the one I mentioned. So using prettier on save doesn't let me break things

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, like epascarello mentioned that works for simple formatting but doesn't seem to work for the situation I specified above. On the other hand, using prettier doesn't allow me to save if there are code-breaking errors, so I'll take that as a solution

Comment: Isn’t this what testing is for? Run tests to see if the code is broken and warn the developer something is broken